# How do I create new tasks TI RTOS?

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, rtos

I've been trying to develope an APP for the CC2650 from TI. Im working with the SimpleBLEperipheral example.
What I want to do is:

- read a UART (up to 80 byte length)
- Write the message to a characteristic

The messages come once a second. Here is, where the problem begins:
When I send a request to the device, that is connected via UART, I get a short answer, that is mixed with the messages, that are secondly sent.
In my App I read the UART once a second in the SimpleBLEPeripheral_performPeriodicTask of the example.
The answers, that come in between the messages will not be read, because of timing problems. My idea was to create a task only for reading the UART and use a callback, but that doesnt seem to work. When I create another task, the App doesnt work at all. No task gets called and the device doesnt advertise.
HELP!

Comment: A task that reads the UART seems like a plausible solution.  But no one is going to be able to help with your specific problem if you don't show a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can see the whole example code in your TI folder. The changes I did are: 
- I created a new task with: 
`void SimpleBLEPeripheral_createTask_read(void)
{
 Task_Params taskParams_read;
  Task_Params_init(&taskParams_read);
  taskParams_read.stack = sbpTaskStack_read;
  taskParams_read.stackSize = SBP_TASK_STACK_SIZE_read;
  taskParams_read.priority = SBP_TASK_PRIORITY_read;

  Task_construct(&sbpTask_read, SimpleBLEPeripheral_taskFxn_read, &taskParams_read, NULL);
}`
and called the function in main, before the BIOS_start()